# How to add Kontakt.io beacons sdk in gradle build of android studio?

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone

I have tried to add using the below line in build.gradle file.
compile 'com.kontakt.sdk.android:library:2.1.0'

It shows error in fetching the build files
But for the sdk verion 1.0.6 its working 
compile 'com.kontakt.sdk.android:library:1.0.6'

Please suggest me the correct path
build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.slotic"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.kontakt.sdk.android:library:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you post what the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: Gradle didn't worked. Added jar as library.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Kontakt.io Android Proximity SDK https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-android-sdk on GitHub.

- Click the Download ZIP button
- Un-zip the file to a temporary location.
- Add the jar file in your Android Studio Project.
- File -> New Module -> Import .JAR/ .AAR Package -> Click Next -> Browse the SDK path (2.1.1) -> Finish (Take time to add in the project)
- Then, Add module in dependencies
- Right Click on Project Name -> Open Module Settings -> Under the list (Modules) -> Click on Dependencies -> Click on '+' -> Module Dependency -> Add Kontakt.io-android-sdk
- Now Build your project It worked for me to kontakt io SDK. If anybody find the way to do this as Gradle build, please let me know.

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

Comment: I am new to stack. I will follow this in future.